# Development environment to use/learn VTK with C++

Tags: c++, editor, development-environment, vtk

I am a newbie with VTK and C++ (but am well versed in the concepts/Java etc). I will eventually need to use both QT and VTK for my project. I would like to know if there is a development environment or editor for VTK (using C++) similar to [VTK Designer](http://www.vcreatelogic.com/products/vtkd/)? With VTK Designer I am very disappointed that there is no feature to convert the VTK output into C++ code.

Comment: Just wanted to add that using a scripting language such as Python or TCL etc is out-of-question for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been working with VTK/Qt for a while, and I doubt there is something like VTK Designer that will convert a pipeline to C++ code.

Everything will need to be hand coded in - and its fairly simple. If you are not sure about the exact C++ implementation of your pipeline, I recommend looking at the VTK samples / tests at http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classes.html

For example, if you would like to implement the vtkStreamLine filter for streamlines, go to the Doxygen page for the class ( http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkStreamLine.html ) and click on the ["Tests" link](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/c2__vtk__t__16.html#c2_vtk_t_vtkStreamLine) to look at existing implementations of the class that has examples of how to setup the pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out the [VTK examples](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples) as they provide numerous examples (largely in C++). You can also look at the Doxygen pages, tests and examples for the classes you are interested in.

[ParaView](http://www.paraview.org/) uses VTK, and you can trace what you do in ParaView to get Python code out (Tools->Python Shell->Trace). I think ParaView with its trace functionality may get you close to what you want. There are of course other resources such as the VTK books, wiki, mailing lists, etc.